# Interpolated map of europe

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a question regarding constructing an interpolated map using PC axes. I have used the package `maps` and `akima` for drawing the map and interpolation. Here is my code:

```
map<-read.table("RACES_GEOREF.txt", row.names=1)
x<-as.numeric(map[,1])
y<-as.numeric(map[,2])
z<-as.numeric(bca.res$li[,1])
x0<-seq(min(map[,1]), max(map[,1]), le=500)
y0<-seq(min(map[,2]), max(map[,2]),le=500)
z.hat<-interp(x, y, z, xo=x0, yo=y0, linear=FALSE, extrap=TRUE)
myGrid<-expand.grid(x0,y0)
temp<-map.where(database="world", x=myGrid[,1], y=myGrid[,2])
toKeep<-grep("France",temp, ignore.case=TRUE)
toRemove<-setdiff(1:length(z.hat$z), toKeep)
z.hat$z[toRemove]<-NA
image(z.hat)
map(add=TRUE, lwd=3)
contour(temp, add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

In the `grep` part, I can only plot the interpolated map for France while I want to do it for France, Germany, UK, Sweden, Italy and Morocco. How can I add these countries to France?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the OR operator in regex:

```
toKeep<-grep("France|Germany|UK|Sweden|Italy|Morocco", temp, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

If I am correct in this you really should change the title of the question since the issue does not appear to be about the interpolation process but about selection of named regions.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that with grep you will need to do something like this:

```
toKeep<-c(grep("France",temp, ignore.case=TRUE),grep("Germany",temp, ignore.case=TRUE),grep("UK",temp, ignore.case=TRUE),grep("Sweden",temp, ignore.case=TRUE),grep("Italy",temp, ignore.case=TRUE),grep("Morocco",temp, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

because grep just return the position in the vector where the name matches.

Comment: Dwin's solution is much better, but I would propose to use an apply loop instead of just repeating the command, e.g. something like: `sapply(c("France", "Germany", etc), grep, temp, ignore.case = TRUE)`.